# Stuck on a class activity. Looking for a quick lesson. Complex Numbers

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, numbers, complex-numbers

I am having troubles grasping the purpose of classes. I was unable to properly complete this assignment, but I need to know this for the exam. The outputs I am currently receiving are

(7, 1)

(7, 1)

(7, 1)

This obviously isn't correct. If someone could explain the thought process of this problem, I would be very grateful. I was unable to figure it out. (New to coding and the teacher hasn't taught this material, yet assigned this question for homework)

The function names and variables cannot be changed. Thank you again.

```
# Goal: complete the three functions multiply, divide and power below
#
#   - self is Complex, which is a complex number whose Re is self.real and
#       Im is self.imag
#   - multiply(c) replaces self by self times c, where c is Complex
#   - divide(c) is to replace self by self divided by c
#   - power(n) is to replace self by self to the power n
#
#   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number
#
# Submission:
#   file name: EX9_8.py
#   Do not change the function and class names and parameters
#   Upload to Vocareum by the due date
#
#

import math

class Complex:
    def __init__ (self, r, i ):  
        self.real = r
        self.imag = i 

        # Copy the three functions from Activity 1 of vLec9_8
    def magnitude(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.real**2 + self.imag**2)

    def conjugate(self):
        self.imag *= -1

    def add(self, c):
        if not isinstance(c, Complex):
            return "Type Mismatch Error"
        self.real += c.real
        self.imag += c.imag

    #The Following Functions are the assignment I am working on. The above functions were already given.

    def multiply(self, c):
        new = (self.real + self.imag) * (c.real + c.imag)
        return new

        #Procedural method: multiply self by c to change self where c is Complex

    def divide(self, c):
        new2 = ((self.real + self.imag)*(c.real - c.imag))/((c.real + c.imag)*(c.real - c.imag))
        return new2

        #Procedural method: divide self by c to change self where c is Complex

    def power(self, n):
        new3 = math.cos(n.real) + ((n.imag)*(math.sin(n.real)))
        return new3

        # Procedural method: take self to the power n to change self,
        #   where n is a positive integer

# test code
c1 = Complex(3,2)
c2 = Complex(4,-1)
c1.add(c2)
print((c1.real, c1.imag))
c1.power(4)
print((c1.real, c1.imag))
c1.divide(c2)
print((c1.real, c1.imag))
# should prints
#(7, 1)
#(2108, 1344)
#(416.94117647058823, 440.2352941176471)
```

Comment: Well, actually, none of your class methods except of `conjugate` and `add` is modifying `self.real` and `self.imag`, so (7, 1) - is correct output

Comment: "...(7, 1), (7, 1), (7, 1)..This obviously isn't correct", what should the correct output be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure the methods you're writing like the `add` method that was provided. Rather than `return`ing some value, you need to assign new values to `self.real` and `self.imag`. The calculations for multiplication, division and exponentiation are a bit more complicated than for addition, so you'll probably need some temporary variables to hold values while you're calculating.

Rather than do the whole thing for you, I'll just do `multiply` which will give you a framework you can use for the others:

```
def multiply(self, c):
    if not isinstance(c, Complex):     # type checking code copied from add()
        return "Type Mismatch Error"   # raising an exception would probably be better

    new_real = self.real * c.real - self.imag * c.imag
    new_imag = self.real * c.imag + c.real * self.imag

    self.real = new_real
    self.imag = new_imag
```

For division, you may want another temp variable to hold the real value you'd get from multiplying `c` by its complex conjugate. Both expressions for the new values can use that intermediate value.